# Faulty pop-up sub-menu being covered by column-styled ul column beneath

Tags: css

With respect to this [working model of the website here](https://siliconharvest.com.au), you will observe that whereas in Chrome, the menu works properly:

[image]

in Microsoft Edge, the behaviour of the z-stacking is inconsistent, and the pop up sub-menu is covered by the colum-styled ul underneath.

[image]

CSS for the column-styled sub-menus:

```
/* Split product category menu into 5 columns */
#menu-item-271293 > ul{
    -moz-column-count: 5;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 5;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
    column-count: 5;
    column-gap: 20px;
    font-size: 20%;
}
```

What I have tried:

```
z-index:10000000!important;

overflow: visible!important;
```

on the relevant elements.

Please inspect menu in browser developer mode and help me to come up with a fix for Microsoft Edge.

Comment: I would probably use flex-box instead of this column proprety.